# Django Model Form is_valid returning False always

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, my is_valid() doesn't seem to work here, my code:

forms.py:

```
class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ['album']
```

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=save_path)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    width = models.FloatField(default=100)
    length = models.FloatField(default=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(ImageAlbum, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.image
```

views.py

```
    def create_listing(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        print('form.is_valid working')
    
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html")

form = ImageForm()

return render(request, 'auctions/new_listing.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

EDITED:
After attempting to fix it with request.FILES, still not working. 
edited views.py code as follows:

```
def create_listing(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print('form.is_valid working')
    
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html")

form = ImageForm()

return render(request, 'auctions/new_listing.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

Comment: Files come in `request.FILES`. Use `form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads.

Comment: ahh got you, this must be the problem. I am checking it now

Comment: Nop, still not working with form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

Comment: You can debug it with something like `print(form.errors.as_data())`.

Comment: it printed out this: {'image': [ValidationError(['This field is required.'])]}. I did upload image to this form.

Comment: Then probably the error is in your template with the `form` tag. Make sure to have `<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">`, otherwise files aren't posted

Comment: Yep, it was the form forgot to add the enctype. Perks of starting new, forgetting things lol. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Web basics ;-) you'll get the hang. From here on out, it's all just copy'n'paste :D